# Spring Security WebSecurityConfig need secured and unsecured zones

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, servlet-filters

Trying to get my **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** to put things in the "/secured/" context behind some filters, and then other URLs are not behind these filters.

Here's what I have so far, but everything is hitting the TokenFilter

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/secured/**").addFilterBefore(new TokenAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthService, environment), 
            ExceptionTranslationFilter.class).
            addFilterBefore(new RequestContentBufferFilter(), TokenAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .antMatcher("/**").anonymous()
            .and().csrf().disable();

}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the **WebSecurity** context to add a blacklist of endpoints for security to ignore like this:

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web
    .ignoring()
       .antMatchers("/metrics**")
       .antMatchers("/health**")
       .antMatchers("/logfile**")
       .antMatchers("/systemcheck**");
}
```